# `foreign_type` relationship failing on Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to understand this relationship setup on this model, and why is this an issue on Rails 6.

Coming from Rails 3, this relationship is defined as:

```
belongs_to :entity foreign_key: 'user_id', foreign_type: 'ruby_type'
```

This worked fine, all the way up to Rails 5 (At least our crawl and traceroute did not bring this as an issue).

However, once we got to Rails 6, we found the following:

```
ArgumentError: Unknown key: :foreign_type. Valid keys are: :class_name, :anonymous_class, :primary_key, :foreign_key, :dependent, :validate, :inverse_of, :strict_loading, :autosave, :required, :touch, :polymorphic, :counter_cache, :optional, :default
```

Was this syntax changed for Rails 6?

Comment: is it a polymorphic association?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[foreign_type option can only be applied together with polymorphic](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5cfd58bbfb8425ab1931c618d98b649bab059ce6/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/belongs_to.rb#L11) - so make sure this is a polymorphic association you are after. If the association is not polymorphic I would get rid of foreign_type.

```
belongs_to :entity, foreign_key: 'user_id', foreign_type: 'ruby_type', polymorphic: true
```